# How can I see which MFC version an executable needs?

Tags: c++, mfc

How can I see which MFC (Microsoft Foundation Classes) Version an executable needs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried using [depends.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235265.aspx)? It will show you which MFC DLL it's linked to.

Comment: Great tool. Just what I needed.

Answer (score 2):

[Dependency Walker 2.2](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) (depends.exe)

> By using [depends.exe](http://www.dependencywalker.com/), or the [DUMPBIN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/756as972.aspx)
>   utility with the /DEPENDENTS option,
>   you can see a list of DLLs that
>   statically link to your application
>   and a list of the application's
>   delay-loaded DLLs.
>
> Dependency Walker is a free utility
>   that scans any 32-bit or 64-bit
>   Windows module (exe, dll, ocx, sys,
>   etc.) and builds a hierarchical tree
>   diagram of all dependent modules. For
>   each module found, it lists all the
>   functions that are exported by that
>   module, and which of those functions
>   are actually being called by other
>   modules. Another view displays the
>   minimum set of required files, along
>   with detailed information about each
>   file including a full path to the
>   file, base address, version numbers,
>   machine type, debug information, and
>   more.
>
> Dependency Walker is also very useful
>   for troubleshooting system errors
>   related to loading and executing
>   modules. Dependency Walker detects
>   many common application problems such
>   as missing modules, invalid modules,
>   import/export mismatches, circular
>   dependency errors, mismatched machine
>   types of modules, and module
>   initialization failures.